# how to get only the Date without time and GMT?

Tags: android

I am trying to get only the date from the Date object but currently i get only the following output:

```
"Thu Nov 24 17:46:14 GMT +02:00 2016"
```

and i would like to get:

```
"24/11/2016"
```

this is my code:

```
 public String getNextYearDate(){
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); // to get previous year add -1
 Date nextYear = cal.getTime();
 return nextYear.toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `SimpleDateFormat` with `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
String output = df.format(nextYear);
```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

 int mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int mMonth = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1;
 int mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

String result = ""+mDay+"/"+mMonth+"/"+mYear ;
```